# How can I make this navigation bar responsive, making it become accessible with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

So here is my HTML:

```
    <div class = "nav">
        <div class = "top_page">
            <h1 class = "mainTitle">title</h1>
            <p class = "slogan">Slogan</p>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class = "container">
            <nav class="center-links">
                <a href="/about" class = "content" >About</a>
                <a href="/projects" class = "content" >Work</a>
                <a href="/recruit" class = "content" >Contact</a>
                <a href="/recruit" class = "content" >Recruit</a></li>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
```

and my current CSS for it (screens width over 808px):

```
.center-links {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.center-links a {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #212A5C;
    border: 1px solid #212A5C;
    color: #FA3400;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1.5%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.center-links a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
```

With what CSS/jQuery/Javascript code can I collapse this menu in a [Bar Icon from awesome fonts](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/bars/) that will display the link with a click?
Thanks! Not using bootstrap

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15227/   ...

Comment: you want a drop down menu ? instead of horizontal nav-tabs?

Comment: I want a drop-down menu when the screen has a certain width

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap than you need to use this markup to do what you want:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="navigation">
              <input type="hidden" id="pagesNr" value="2"/>
                  <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                              <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand ">Company Name</a>
          </div>
         <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav scroll-nav" id="sortableMenuItems">
                  <li">
                     <a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                   <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
               </li>
          </ul>
     </nav>
 </div>
```

When you see this menu in small devices it will be collapsed showing the 'hamburger' icon on the right side.

To answer your reply I have updated this, so to use bootstrap you need to put in the 'head' tag of your HTML page the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The work around of this using your code is to make an hidden dropdown menu which will appear when the browser will be resized at a certain defined width, and for this you have to use @media queries. But I really believe that this is not the option you have to follow.

Comment: if I don't use bootstrap?

Comment: There is any reason why you don't use it?

Comment: don't know how to use it yet

Comment: @FlipFloop I have updated my answer so you can read how to load the bootstrap framework and 'jQuery'. Once you do this you will able to use it and try the example menu I have provided for you. This is really not so hard to learn and also gives you the tool to build modern and responsive web sites. And I think that is what you want to do.